# Is there a more efficient way to pass in all the fixtures?

Tags: playwright

I'm new to Playwright so please forgive me if I don't use the vernacular correctly.

I have some long end to end test cases to write up that require several different backend webservice connections as well as multiple pages.  Is  there a more efficient way to pass in all the fixtures?  Having to pass in 20+ fixtures to each test is going to be pretty ugly.

```
test('Smoke Test 1', async ({ loginForm, 
    detailForm, 
    listForm, 
    arrayForm, 
    addressForm, 
    confirmationForm, 
    configForm, 
    cartForm, 
    miniCartForm, 
    emailListForm, 
    cardForm, 
    authorizationForm, 
    bankForm, 
    routingForm, 
    webServiceClient1, 
    webServiceClient2, 
    webServiceClient3, 
    webServiceClient4, 
    webServiceClient5, 
    webServiceClient6, 
    webServiceClient7, 
    page    
}) => {
    await loginForm.login('jsmith', 'password');
    const response = await webServiceClient1.getSomeData();
    console.log(`VIN: ${response.data}`);
    //use other forms and webservices
});
```

This is going to get really crazy for each test.

Comment: Have you tried [merge fixtures](https://playwright.dev/docs/release-notes#merge-test-fixtures) ?

Comment: @KlimBim, I see the documentation about mergeTests but I don't see anything about merging fixtures.  What will merging fixtures do for me?  Will I only have to pass in a single fixture?

Comment: could a [mixin](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/8346) help you? I am having your issue as well but I don´t have as many fixtures as you have. What I could recommend , you can have a "merged-pom" where you host your locators of your ```xxxForms``` respectively your POMs. Why not having a sub-POM which takes your frequently used ```xxxForm```-POMs and add them to one fixture. Then you only need to call one fixture for instance.

Comment: One more thing which I use to reduce my imports at tests. I have a fixture which ```use```s a function. The function is very easy and at the moment it returns ```string[]``` However, why not returning your"forms"? e.g. ```base.extend<{my_collection_function: any}>({ my_collection_function: async ({}, use) => { await use(my_collection_of_frequently_used_forms)}})``` and this function returns a map/dictionary

Comment: Maybe don't destructure all of the params, then access them on the non-destructured parameter object? You can destructure the ones you don't want to be prefixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started looking at my fixture file.

fixtures.ts:

```
import { test as base } from '@playwright/test';
import { DetailFormControl, HomePageControl, SearchResultsControl } from './page';
import { WebService1Client } from 'data/clients/web-service-one-client';

type MyFixtures = {
    detailFormControl: DetailFormControl;
    homePageControl: HomePageControl;
    webService1Client: WebService1Client;
    searchResultsControl: SearchResultsControl;
};

export const test = base.extend<MyFixtures>({

detailFormControl: async ({ page }, use) => {
    await use(new detailFormControl(page));
},

homePageControl: async ({ page }, use) => {
    await use(new HomePageControl(page));
},

searchResultsControl: async ({ page }, use) => {
    await use(new SearchResultsControl(page));
},

webService1Client: async({ }, use) => {
    const webService1Client = new WebService1Client(
        `http://www.webservice1.com`
    );
    await use(webService1Client);
}

// about another twenty of these here
});
export { expect, type Page } from '@playwright/test';
```

And then realized that I could do this - this is called a Composed Fixture:

```
import { test as base } from '@playwright/test';
import { LoginFormControl, HomePageControl, SearchResultsControl } from '../page';
import { WebServiceClient } from 'data/clients/webservice.client';

type MyFixtures = {
    controls: {
        loginFormControl: LoginFormControl;
        homePageControl: HomePageControl;
        searchResultsControl: SearchResultsControl;
    };
    clients: {
      webServiceClient: WebServiceClient;
    }
};

export const test = base.extend<MyFixtures>({
    controls: async ({ page }, use) => {
        const controls = {
            loginFormControl: new LoginFormControl(page),
            homePageControl: new HomePageControl(page),
            searchResultsControl: new SearchResultsControl(page),
        };
    await use(controls);
    },

    clients: async ({ }, use) => {
        const clients = {
          webServiceClient: new WebServiceClient (
              `http://www.mywebservice.com`
          )
        };
    await use(clients);
    }
});  

export { expect, type Page } from '@playwright/test';
```

Then in my spec files I could do this:

```
import { test, expect } from '../fixtures/myFixture.ts';

test.describe('Test something', () => {
    test('Test Case 1', async ({ controls, clients, page    }) => {
        
        await controls.loginFormControl.login('jsmith', 'password');
        const response = await clients.webServiceClient.getData();
        console.log(`VIN: ${response.data}`);
    });
});
```

I hope this is helpful!

Answer (score 1):

@Anton

In regard to my comment I figured out a new approach which works for me pretty well. Disadvantage is, you have to write a fixture and include your `xyz_Form`´s and pass them to `use({...})`

**pom1.ts**

```js
export class POM1{
    async test(){
        console.log('test works')
    }
}
```

**fixture.ts**

```js
import {test as base} from '@playwright/test';
import {POM1} from 'pom1'

/**
 * 
 */
export const test = base.extend<{ container }>({
    container : async ({page}, use) => {
        const pom_1 = new POM1(page)
        const pom_2 = new POM2(page)
        const pom_3 = new POM3(page)
        await use({pom_1, pom_2, pom_3})
    }
})
export {expect} from '@playwright/test'
```

**test.spec.ts**

```js
    test('', async ({ container }) => {
        container.pom_1.test()
        container.pom_2.<different_method_of_POM2()>
        ...
    })
```

Comment: Thank you, Klim!  I thought a lot about your solution and built a bit on top of it.

Answer (score 0):

### [Merge test fixtures](https://playwright.dev/docs/release-notes#merge-test-fixtures)

You can now merge test fixtures from multiple files or modules:

**fixtures.ts**

```
import { mergeTests } from '@playwright/test';
import { test as dbTest } from 'database-test-utils';
import { test as a11yTest } from 'a11y-test-utils';

export const test = mergeTests(dbTest, a11yTest);
```

**test.spec.ts**

```
import { test } from './fixtures';

test('passes', async ({ database, page, a11y }) => {
  // use database and a11y fixtures.
});
```

References:
[Using multiple test fixtures in a single test with Playwright](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70641332/using-multiple-test-fixtures-in-a-single-test-with-playwright/77393564#)

Comment: How exactly does that help me?

Comment: Don't just drop the documentation from the Playwright website - I've already read that too.  Please explain how it solves the question posed.

Comment: It seems you are mixing Page objects with fixtures.

Comment: They are two different concepts.

Comment: I figured it out.  Needed to use a Composed Fixture.